# Renaming part files of PIG output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a requirement of changing the part file naming convention after running my PIG job. I want `part-r-0000` to be `userdefinedName-r-0000`.

Any possible solution to that?
**I am avoiding hadoop -cp and hadoop -mv commands**.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This files are created by map-reduce jobs generated by Pig. So you should configure Apache Map-reduce. The corresponding property is `mapreduce.output.basename`

You can define any Hadoop property directly in your pig script:

```
SET mapreduce.output.basename 'custom-name';
```

Answer (score 1):

> Starting the pig like this would do the same
>
> ```
>  pig -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=my-queue -Dmapreduce.output.basename=my-outputfilename;
> ```